# mysql CREATE DATABASE using variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written an SQL script to create a database. But I can't seem to figure out how to declare a string variable and reference it afterwards in SQL code. I figure this is a very basic sort of thing, so I must be confused about something here.

All the examples I found use the `SET` keyword.

```
SET @dbname = "mydb";
CREATE DATABASE @dbname;
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use variables in place of identifiers (database name, table name, column name, etc). You can only use variables in place of scalar values. To use a variable as an identifier, you have to use PREPARE on a string to make a [dynamic SQL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```
SET @dbname = 'mydb';
SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE `', @dbname, '`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

Re your comment:

For initialization scripts, you can format any text you want, usually with a scripting language like python or ruby or even bash, and then run the script as input to the [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).

As long as you substitute the name of the database into the CREATE DATABASE statement before sending the statement to the SQL parser, it's fine.

You have to keep in mind that from its earliest conception, SQL was meant to be used in combination from some other programming language. SQL is not as good at being a standalone language as most languages. SQL is a [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), just for manipulating data and metadata. Other languages are better for general-purpose programming.

Comment: So what is best practice for creating database initialisation scripts without redundantly writing out identifiers? Should I use a shell script and call mysql commands from there? Or are PREPARE statement the standard solution to this? Or does everyone just redundantly write out the identifier?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot SET a variable before you DECLARE it, change it to DECLARE and it will work.

EDIT: see code example.

```
DECLARE @dbname varchar(500) = "mydb"
CREATE DATABASE @dbname
```

Comment: Replacing SET with DECLARE was not successful.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean in sql code in your answer? That might clear things up. The error I am getting is "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @dbname = mydb' at line 1".

Comment: Still error. The entirety of my sql script contains just what you put in your answer. Could I be missing some basic initialization stuff?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to downvote this answer, because it's using syntax that only works in Microsoft SQL Server, despite the OP tagging their question with [tag:mysql]. You should pay attention to the brand of RDBMS the question is about, and give an answer that works with that brand. Not every database in the world is Microsoft.